# .NET: Get all Outlook calendar items

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, calendar, recurring

How can I get all items from a specific calendar (for a specific date). 
Lets say for instance that I have a calendar with a recurring item every Monday evening. When I request all items like this:

```
CalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
CalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
```

I only get 1 item...

Is there an easy way to get **all** items (main item + derived items) from a calendar?
In my specific situation it can be possible to set a date limit but it would be cool just to get all items (my recurring items are time limited themselves).

**I'm using the Microsoft Outlook 12 Object library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook)**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that you must Restrict or Find in order to get recurring appointments, otherwise Outlook won't expand them. Also, you must Sort by Start *before* setting IncludeRecurrences.

Comment: Please be aware that we encountered significant performance penalties (up to 30 seconds instead of some ms) on some systems/data sets when sorting the items.

Answer (score 36):

I've studied the docs and this is my result:
I've put a time limit of one month hard-coded, but this is just an example.

```
public void GetAllCalendarItems()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

    oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
    CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
    outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
    {
        if (item.IsRecurring)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp = item.GetRecurrencePattern();
            DateTime first = new DateTime(2008, 8, 31, item.Start.Hour, item.Start.Minute, 0);
            DateTime last = new DateTime(2008, 10, 1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem recur = null;



            for (DateTime cur = first; cur <= last; cur = cur.AddDays(1))
            {
                try
                {
                    recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur);
                    MessageBox.Show(recur.Subject + " -> " + cur.ToLongDateString());
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Subject + " -> " + item.Start.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I wrote similar code, but then found the export functionality:

```
Application outlook;
NameSpace OutlookNS;

outlook = new ApplicationClass();
OutlookNS = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

MAPIFolder f = OutlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

CalendarSharing cs = f.GetCalendarExporter();
cs.CalendarDetail = OlCalendarDetail.olFullDetails;
cs.StartDate = new DateTime(2011, 11, 1);
cs.EndDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 31);
cs.SaveAsICal("c:\\temp\\cal.ics");
```

Answer (score 5):

LinqPad snipped that works for me:

```
//using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Application a = new Application();
Items i = a.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items;
i.IncludeRecurrences = true;
i.Sort("[Start]");
i = i.Restrict(
    "[Start] >= '10/1/2013 12:00 AM' AND [End] < '10/3/2013 12:00 AM'");


var r =
    from ai in i.Cast<AppointmentItem>()
    select new {
        ai.Categories,
        ai.Start,
        ai.Duration
        };
r.Dump();
```

Comment: i would also note that reversing the order of the sort and includerecurrences didn't seem to matter when i was testing it. YMMV but I used this recently and it returned duplicates for the days given. My final query was for 6 months of data though, not for just a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

If you need want to access the shared folder from your friend, then you can set your friend as the recipient. Requirement: his calendar must be shared first.

```
// Set recepient
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oNS.CreateRecipient("abc@yourmail.com");

// Get calendar folder 
Outlook.MAPIFolder oCalendar = oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to expand recurring items manually. Just ensure you sort the items *before* using IncludeRecurrences.

Here is VBA example:

```
tdystart = VBA.Format(#8/1/2012#, "Short Date")
tdyend = VBA.Format(#8/31/2012#, "Short Date")

Dim folder As MAPIFolder
Set appointments = folder.Items

appointments.Sort "[Start]" ' <-- !!! Sort is a MUST
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = True ' <-- This will expand reccurent items

Set app = appointments.Find("[Start] >= """ & tdystart & """ and [Start] <= """ & tdyend & """")

While TypeName(app) <> "Nothing"
   MsgBox app.Start & " " & app.Subject
   Set app = appointments.FindNext
Wend
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void GetAllCalendarItems()
        {
            DataTable sample = new DataTable(); //Sample Data
            sample.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
            sample.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
            sample.Columns.Add("StartTime", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("EndTime", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("StartDate", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("EndDate", typeof(DateTime));
            sample.Columns.Add("AllDayEvent", typeof(bool));
            sample.Columns.Add("Body", typeof(string));


            listViewContacts.Items.Clear();
            oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            oCalenderFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            outlookCalendarItems = oCalenderFolder.Items;
            outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
           // DataTable sample = new DataTable();
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
            {
                DataRow row = sample.NewRow();
                row["Subject"] = item.Subject;
                row["Location"] = item.Location;
                row["StartTime"] = item.Start.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                row["EndTime"] = item.End.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                row["StartDate"] = item.Start.Date;
                row["EndDate"] = item.End.Date;
                row["AllDayEvent"] = item.AllDayEvent;
                row["Body"] = item.Body;
                sample.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            sample.AcceptChanges();
            foreach (DataRow dr in sample.Rows)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dr["Subject"].ToString());

                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["Location"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["StartTime"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["EndTime"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["StartDate"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["EndDate"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["AllDayEvent"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["Body"].ToString());



                    this.listViewContacts.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            oApp = null;
            oNS = null;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this article very useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-search-and-obtain-appointments-in-a-time-range

It demonstrates how to get calendar entries in a specified time range. It worked for me. Here is the source code from the article for your convenience :)

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

private void DemoAppointmentsInRange()
{
    Outlook.Folder calFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
        as Outlook.Folder;
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime end = start.AddDays(5);
    Outlook.Items rangeAppts = GetAppointmentsInRange(calFolder, start, end);
    if (rangeAppts != null)
    {
        foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem appt in rangeAppts)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine("Subject: " + appt.Subject 
                 + " Start: " + appt.Start.ToString("g"));
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get recurring appointments in date range.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folder"></param>
/// <param name="startTime"></param>
/// <param name="endTime"></param>
/// <returns>Outlook.Items</returns>
private Outlook.Items GetAppointmentsInRange(
    Outlook.Folder folder, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    string filter = "[Start] >= '"
        + startTime.ToString("g")
        + "' AND [End] <= '"
        + endTime.ToString("g") + "'";
    Debug.WriteLine(filter);
    try
    {
        Outlook.Items calItems = folder.Items;
        calItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
        calItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);
        Outlook.Items restrictItems = calItems.Restrict(filter);
        if (restrictItems.Count > 0)
        {
            return restrictItems;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a combination of a few answers to get entries from the past 30 days.  Will output to console but you can take the console log output and save to a file or whatever you want from there. Thanks to everyone for posting their code here, was very helpful!

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

void GetAllCalendarItems()
{

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = false;

Console.WriteLine("Showing Calendar Items From the last 30 days");

//Set your dates here...
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

string filter = "[Start] >= '"
    + startTime.ToString("g")
    + "' AND [End] <= '"
    + endTime.ToString("g") + "'";

try
{

    outlookCalendarItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);


    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems.Restrict(filter))
    {

        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject + " -> " + item.Start.ToLongDateString());

    }


}
catch {  }


Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}


GetAllCalendarItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public List<AdxCalendarItem> GetAllCalendarItems()
    {
        Outlook.Application OutlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        List<AdxCalendarItem> result = new List<AdxCalendarItem>();
            Outlook._NameSpace session = OutlookApp.Session;
            if (session != null)
                try
                {
                    object stores = session.GetType().InvokeMember("Stores", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, session, null);
                    if (stores != null)
                        try
                        {
                            int count = (int)stores.GetType().InvokeMember("Count", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, stores, null);
                            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                            {
                                object store = stores.GetType().InvokeMember("Item", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, stores, new object[] { i });
                                if (store != null)
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Outlook.MAPIFolder calendar = null;
                                        try
                                        {
                                            calendar = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)store.GetType().InvokeMember("GetDefaultFolder", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, store, new object[] { Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar });
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                        if (calendar != null)
                                            try
                                            {
                                                Outlook.Folders folders = calendar.Folders;
                                                try
                                                {
                                                    Outlook.MAPIFolder subfolder = null;
                                                    for (int j = 1; j < folders.Count + 1; j++)
                                                    {
                                                        subfolder = folders[j];
                                                        try
                                                        {
                                                           // add subfolder items
                                                            result.AddRange(GetAppointmentItems(subfolder));
                                                        }
                                                        finally
                                                        { if (subfolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(subfolder); }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                finally
                                                { if (folders != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folders); }
                                                // add root items
                                                result.AddRange(GetAppointmentItems(calendar));
                                            }
                                            finally { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(calendar); }
                                    }
                                    finally { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(store); }
                            }
                        }
                        finally { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(stores); }
                }
                finally { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session); }
        return result;
    }

    List<AdxCalendarItem> GetAppointmentItems(Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder)
    {
        List<AdxCalendarItem> result = new List<AdxCalendarItem>();
        Outlook.Items calendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;
        try
        {
            calendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
            Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = null;
            for (int j = 1; j < calendarItems.Count + 1; j++)
            {
                appointment = calendarItems[j] as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
                try
                {
                    AdxCalendarItem item = new AdxCalendarItem(
                        calendarFolder.Name,
                        appointment.Subject,
                                   appointment.Location,
                                   appointment.Start,
                                   appointment.End,
                                   appointment.Start.Date,
                                   appointment.End.Date,
                                   appointment.AllDayEvent,
                                   appointment.Body);
                    result.Add(item);
                }
                finally
                {
                    { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appointment); }
                }
            }
        }
        finally { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(calendarItems); }
        return result;
    }
}

public class AdxCalendarItem
{
    public string CalendarName;
    public string Subject;
    public string Location;
    public DateTime StartTime;
    public DateTime EndTime;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public bool AllDayEvent;
    public string Body;

    public AdxCalendarItem(string CalendarName, string Subject, string Location, DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime,
                            DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, bool AllDayEvent, string Body)
    {
        this.CalendarName = CalendarName;
        this.Subject = Subject;
        this.Location = Location;
        this.StartTime = StartTime;
        this.EndTime = EndTime;
        this.StartDate = StartDate;
        this.EndDate = EndDate;
        this.AllDayEvent = AllDayEvent;
        this.Body = Body;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

    oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
    CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
    outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
    {
        if (item.IsRecurring)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp = item.GetRecurrencePattern();

                   // get all date 
            DateTime first = new DateTime( item.Start.Hour, item.Start.Minute, 0);
            DateTime last = new DateTime();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem recur = null;



            for (DateTime cur = first; cur <= last; cur = cur.AddDays(1))
            {
                try
                {
                    recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur);
                    MessageBox.Show(recur.Subject + " -> " + cur.ToLongDateString());
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Subject + " -> " + item.Start.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }

}
```

> it is working I try it but you need to add reference about 
>   Microsoft outlook

Answer (score -4):

```
calendarFolder = 
    mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

Comment: this just provides a reference to the calendar folder. doesn't answer the question at all.