# Outlook Filter Items - Get all recurring appointments in a week range

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-2010

I'm trying to get all appointments in outlook in week range, but reoccurring appointments are not showing up.

Here is the code:

```
    var outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    var calendar = outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    calendar.Items.IncludeRecurrences = true;

    string filter = String.Format("[Start] >= {0} And [End] < {1}",
            DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("ddddd h:nn AMPM"),
            DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(5).ToString("ddddd h:nn AMPM"));
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment;
    foreach (var item in calendar.Items.Restrict(filter))
    {
        appointment = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        if (appointment != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(appointment.Start.ToString());
        }
    }
```

How do I get all of the recurring appointments that are displayed in Outlook for a week range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [recurrence pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526361%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx)
Put this inside your loop:

> ```
>      if (item.IsRecurring)
>         {
>             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp = item.GetRecurrencePattern();
>             DateTime first = new DateTime(2011, 11, 7, item.Start.Hour, item.Start.Minute, 0);
>             DateTime last = new DateTime(2011, 12, 1);
>             Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem recur = null;
>
>
>
>             for (DateTime cur = first; cur <= last; cur = cur.AddDays(1))
>             {
>                     recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur);
>                     Console.WriteLine(cur.ToLongDateString());
>             }
>         }
> ```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90899/net-get-all-outlook-calendar-items/92184#92184)
for more info

Comment: That worked great except if I tried to get an appointment for a day that it wasn't scheduled I got an exception.  I've wrapped the recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur); line with a try catch, continue, and it's working great thanks!

Comment: I've duplicated this code but keep getting "You changed one of the recurrences of this item, and this instance no longer exists. Close any open items and try again."

Comment: Apparently Outlook can't be open jeez.