# Include recurring appointments

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to get all appointments from client outlook with python and win32com. client, I just want to get all appointments from 2019 so that I could restrict the appointment Items, but when I restrict them I don't get the recurring appointments.

I already tried to enable recurring items with appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True", but that didn't help.

```py
import win32com.client
import time
import datetime
import os


f=open("mem.txt", "w")
counter=0
outlook= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace=outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
recipient = namespace.createRecipient("Some Calender")
resolved = recipient.Resolve()
sharedCalendar = namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9)
appointments = sharedCalendar.Items

# Restrict items
begin = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2019, 12, 30)
restriction = "[Start] >= '" + begin.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "' AND [End] <= '" +end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + "'"
restrictedItems = appointments.Restrict(restriction)
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"

# Iterate through restricted AppointmentItems
for appointmentItem in restrictedItems:
    month= appointmentItem.Start
    month=str(month)[5:-18] #just trim the month out of the date
    if month=='08': #need appointments from specific
        #mystuff
        #the code works but I want the recurring appointments too
print(counter)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting `IncludeRecurrences` to `True` before Restricting your items ?

Basically switching those two lines :

```
restrictedItems = appointments.Restrict(restriction)
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = "True"
```

Comment: Can you read C# ? I found an answer to the same question but in C#. It says to add in your loop an if-then statement evaluating the IsRecurring property : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044268/11269264

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to retrieve all Outlook appointment items from the folder that meets the predefined condition, you need to sort the items in ascending order and set the `IncludeRecurrences` to true. You will not catch recurrent appointments if you don’t do this before using the Restrict method!

```
    folderItems = folder.Items;
    folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
    folderItems.Sort("[Start]");
    resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
restriction = "[Start] >= '2023-01-01 00:00' AND [End] <= '2023-12-31 23:59'"

restricted_appointments  = appointments.Restrict(restriction)

# includes recurrences and gives the time of the start date of the recurrent event if the start date is not in the time restriction

restricted_appointments.IncludeRecurrences = True # only works if you restrict beforehand: You cannot possibly export all instances of recurring appointments - imagine patterns with no end date.
```