# Accessing A Shared Outlook Calendar Without Installing Outlook?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'm using an approach like the one discussed here ([.NET: Get all Outlook calendar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90899/net-get-all-outlook-calendar-items)) to read Outlook calendar events from a shared calendar.  This works fine locally, but seems to depend on Outlook being installed on the machine.

Is there a way to access the Outlook Calendar without installing Outlook or Office on the machine the app. is running from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked out [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), in particular the RDO objects?

For example, you can use code like this I'm almost 100% sure without Outlook installed:

```
    Dim objRedemption As New Redemption.RDOSession
    objRedemption.Logon()
    Dim objCal = objRedemption.GetSharedDefaultFolder("Dunkin Donuts", Redemption.rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)
    objRedemption.Logoff()
```

("Dunking Donuts", in case you were wondering, is my test mailbox.)

Comment: If Outlook is not installed, there won't be any profiles, so you will need to call RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox. And you will need to have the MAPI system installed for Redemption to work, which means either Outlook or the standalone version of MAPI must be installed (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39045).