# Getting appointments from Outlook in C#

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook

I want to make a simple application in Visual Studio that checks if a certain person has an appointment at the current time. Our company works with the Outlook Calendar, so I'd like to connect that to Visual Studio. I've seen some things out there, but it all seems a bit complex for the goal I want to achieve.

To give an example, I want to know if one of my colleagues has an appointment at this time, so I can set a variable true or false.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This may be somewhere along the lines of what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90899/net-get-all-outlook-calendar-items

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to automate Outlook from your application. The [How to automate Outlook and Word by using Visual C# .NET to create a pre-populated e-mail message that can be edited](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819398) article describes all the required steps. Also you may find the [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) sample project helpful.

In case if you need to develop an Outlook add-in, see [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve user availability, either use `Application.Sesssion.CurrentUser` to retrieve the Recipient object representing the current user or call `Applicatiobn.Session.CreateRecipient` passing the name of the other user. Once you have the Recipient object, call `Recipient.FreeBusy` to retrieve a string representing user availability in the given time range.

Comment: I've been messing around with it a bit, but I get an error everytime I try to execute a very simple program which sends an email:

"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(8000FFFF)".

I tried running the program as an administrator and a tip that Microsoft had on their website, edited a registry value. I only got it to send an email once. I still have exactly the same program, but I can't get the error away.